# Overheating issue in Ubuntu Budgie

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, power-management, overheating, ubuntu-budgie

I have installed Ubuntu Budgie alongside windows in my MSI GL63-9RDS(i5-9300H, 8GB RAM, 4GB 1050TI Geforce GTX, 512GB Nvme SSD). Just after the first day I'm experiencing unusual heating issues when I'm on the Linux while on Windows everything works fine.
Ex. running chrome,Vs code, Spotify stats.
1.Windows- 3 hours straight,no heating,no cooler booster fans required.
2-Ubuntu Budgie- 0.5 hours and heating starts and withing 15 minutes after that, there is a need for cooler booster fans and it remain for rest of the time.
.
.

**What I did till now**
1. Updated thermald
2. Saw if any process is taking unusual CPU using top command.
3. Installed TLP
4. Installed cpufreq for toggling between performance and power save mode.
*Nothing has worked till now*
***Please help***

here is the requested result for **ps auxc | grep therm**

```
root       186  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   May06   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
root       800  0.0  0.1 183620  9196 ?        Ssl  May06   0:00 thermald
```

and yes I have latest nvidia drivers installed. 
// SORRY for late response

edit2:
result for **sensors**:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +37.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

result for **sudo dmidecode -s bios-version**

```
E16P5IMS.301
```

result for **top**

```
top - 13:15:08 up 10 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.72, 0.68, 0.38
Tasks: 305 total,   1 running, 219 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.3 us,  1.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.6 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7994128 total,  4584620 free,  1593860 used,  1815648 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,  2097148 free,        0 used.  5382540 avail Mem
```

The image shows the full description of top command

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3Y9h.png

***nvidia driver version::***   435.21

I am still checking if switching to Intel's inbuilt drivers help or not,I will let you know soon.
..
..
**I have switched to intel drivers now. However I am still noticing some heating (not like before but yes, there is mild heating). This happens when I am using only chrome and vs code. I also notices using top that chrome was using unusual amount of cpu- 70% - 90% sometimes when /i had videos runnug on it. Is that normal for chrome to do it?**

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ps auxc | grep therm`. Also, do you have the latest Nvidia driver installed? If you switch your video to an internal (non-Nvidia) controller, does the heating problem go away?

Comment: I'm doing it wait few minutes

Comment: @heynnema sorry for late response.

Comment: Nvidia or Nouveau drivers? It it the CPU or the GPU that is heating up?

Comment: You already have acpi_thermal_pm installed, so you can uninstall thermald, and TLP, and cpufreq. Install lm-sensors and show me the output of the sensors command. You can install Gnome Shell extension Vitals to monitor your temps. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/. You didn't tell me whether switching off the Nvidia helped or not. What version Nvidia driver? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Also show me `top`.

Comment: @heynnema see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**sensors**

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +37.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Absolutely normal.

**BIOS/Intel ME**

You have BIOS E16P5IMS.301.

There are BIOS E16P5IMS.302 and Intel ME FW (2020-01-03) updates [here](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GL63-9RDS).

**Nvidia**

You have Nvidia v435.21.

There are Nvidia drivers v440.82 [here](https://www.geforce.com/drivers).

**Software**

Uninstall thermald, and TLP, and cpufreq.

Chrome usage will be high when viewed in `top`, whilst playing videos. Normal.

Comment: hey @heynnema thank you so much for being this much dedicated for answering my question. Here is an update though : Since I have switched my graphics to Intel,  heating has stopped apparently. Does that mean something??

Comment: @AshutoshShisodia This is somewhat normal. You can update the BIOS and Intel ME FW, and the Nvidia drivers. And open your computer and make sure that the fan(s) are clear of dust, and are operational.

Comment: Fans are super clean and functional. Do I really need to update Bios as I have seen my friends run into problems after updating it?

Comment: @AshutoshShisodia Always have good backups before updating the BIOS and Intel ME FW... and yes, BIOS and FW updates are very important, and usually they breeze though without a problem. Sometimes after a BIOS update, some settings may need to get checked/reset, and maybe that's what your friends have run into. Quite normal.

Comment: @AshutoshShisodia Is there a fan on the Nvidia card? If so, did you also check it? It's easy to miss.

Comment: @AshutoshShisodia Status please...

Comment: @AshutoshShisodia Status please...

Comment: Hey, @heynnema  I'm sorry , I don't know how to check, I can't see anything below the cover, there are two fans at either side of laptop, and 7 heat pipes.

Comment: @AshutoshShisodia Have you done any portions of my answer?